# Can't access startfile http://localhost/

Tags: docker, containers, images, servers, http

Having created a [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/jetty) container as:

```
docker run -d --name=jetty  jetty
```

How do I now [get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62509854/4531180) a hello world page as?

```
Looking up localhost:8080
Making HTTP connection to localhost:8080
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost:8080/
```

and:

```
Looking up localhost
Making HTTP connection to localhost
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost/
```

containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5379d3f41d20        jetty               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        8080/tcp            jetty
```

Answer (score 1):

created with:

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 jetty
```

gives a start page as:

```
Error 404 - Not Found.

   No context on this server matched or handled this request.

   Contexts known to this server are:

   Context Path Display Name Status LifeCycle
     __________________________________________________________________

   [1]icon  [2]Powered by Eclipse Jetty:// Server
     __________________________________________________________________

References

   1. http://eclipse.org/jetty
   2. http://eclipse.org/jetty
```

Comment: That looks fine to me.